# How to set the size of titles to the standard size?

Tags: titles, parts

In the following MWE, the size of the titles of the parts are one size below the usual size as you can see on the two pictures below. How could I modify that?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%%%% center part titles
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\hfil\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\hfil}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}%espace entre chapitres
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don’t want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{A title}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit\leftmark} % odd pages: book title

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A name}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
    
\frontmatter
\part{Why is Latex so complicated?}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
    
\mainmatter
\part{How to customize a part section?}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `titles of the parts are one size below the usual size`?

Comment: I've just added two pictures to illustrate that point.